# Excel - Date format not converted to Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Can any one help me , how to covert to date format.

how to covert to date format , in image above are in date format and below are general format. how convert and uniform in all dates . Please click on this text to see the image

[image]

Comment: Provide a clear example in the question, we don't download files from an unknown source.

Comment: It means your local is `dd/mm/yyyy` and the data imported is in `mm/dd/yyyy`